# Adding EditTexts to alert dialog - missed code?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I stumbled upon this code on how to make an alert dialog with two edit text inside. 
and after running it, when I press the item, no alert is popping up. 
I'm guessing that I'm missing some basic syntax, any idea?

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Hi there!");
                    alert.setMessage("Got a question? we'd love to hear from you. Send us a message and we'll respond ASAP");

                    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    final EditText titleBox = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                    titleBox.setHint("Title");
                    layout.addView(titleBox); 

                    final EditText descriptionBox = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                    descriptionBox.setHint("Description");
                    layout.addView(descriptionBox); 

                    alert.setView(layout);
                    alert.setPositiveButton("SEND", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // sending the mail from user to harel's mail address
                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            i.setType("message/rfc822");
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"<mail here>"});
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, titleBox.getText());
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , descriptionBox.getText());
                            try {
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog alert1 = alert.create();
                    alert1.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you put in the question is running ok (dialog buttons are missing). Try to check if you set the click listener on the button(the item) to open the dialog, like the example below:

```
buttonExample.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO - your dialog code here.
        }
    });
```

And a little tip: you don't need to create alert1. Just change the last lines with this code:

```
alert.create();
alert.show();
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, Fernando!